# How to set Accept-Language in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, request, browser

I'm trying to set Accept-Language for webbrowser control like this:

```
...
string header = "Accept: application/xml" + Environment.NewLine + "Accept-Language: uk-ua"
var wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(userLink, null, null, header);
```

But this works for **Accept** and doesn't work for **Accept-Language**.

How to set Accept-Language for request from this control?

Answer (score 0):

Following [How To Use WebBrowser HEADERS Param in Navigate Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172998)

> All headers must be terminated with a carriage return linefeed pair.

```
string header = "Accept: application/xml\r\nAccept-Language: uk-ua\r\n";
```

Comment: it could be that you need to 'Include English in the Accept-Language header' following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/965xw3x5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2