# How to set language in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I need to set the language in a `TWebBrowser` component according to some properties of your program. 
The problem is that i have to show, for example, dates according to the specific country dateformat. I already tried to find some hints in the docs, but without success.

So my question is:
Is there some possibility to set the language of a `TWebBrowser` like i can do in a normal instance of `Internet Explorer`?

Comment: web applications usually look at the HTTP request header to detect the language(s) which are chosen by the user as 'preferred' languages - so if the user has configured its language selection for IE, the same should be used for TWebbrowser. Not?

Comment: unfortunaltely not, my language is set to german, if i start it directly in the browser everything works fine, when i call it from my delphi program it's english dateformat

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253916/how-to-set-accept-language-in-webbrowser

Comment: I've tested it, but it also doesn't work with filling the header with an Accept-Language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now solved it with a little workaround:

I pass an additional parameter with the `URL`, describing the language of the User. With this language we decide via `Javascript` which Formats to use.

Of course this is just a workaround and only possible if you can customize the website to call, but i haven't yet found another solution to manage this with `Delphi`.

I would be glad to read some other / better / simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this e.g. for de = German Language like:

```
header_string := 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,'
                 + 'application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
                 +  chr(13) + chr(10)  // Linefeed
                 + 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
                 +  chr(13) + chr(10); // Linefeed 

WebBrowser1.Navigate(url,16,0,header_string);
```